# How do I create a new object for each class instance?

Tags: python

Please look at the code snippet below, I asked the question below

```
class SAMPLES:
    x = np.zeros(10)

    def __init__(self, k, value):
        self.x[k] = value


a = SAMPLES(0, 9)
b = SAMPLES(0, 10)
print(a.x[0])
print(b.x[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
10
10
```

But the output must be:

```
9
10
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Put `self.x = np.zeros(10)` in the `__init__` method. Using a class attribute shares the same array for all instances.

Comment: you're using a _class variable_ but you want an _instance variable_. `x` has the same underlying data across all instances of `SAMPLES`.

Comment: `x` has been declared as a static variable instead of a instance variable. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-and-methods-in-python)

Comment: Thank you all, I noticed the problem

Comment: I edited the title to better express the problem because at first glance I thought you were simply asking how to instantiate a class. But if you want to [edit] it further, by all means. Check out [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @wjandrea, Yes, the title you wrote is correct. thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare `x` within the `__init__` method.

```py
class SAMPLES:
    def __init__(self, k, value):
        self.x = np.zeros(10)
        self.x[k] = value


a = SAMPLES(0, 9)
b = SAMPLES(0, 10)
print(a.x[0])
print(b.x[0])
```

Comment: Correction: *declare* -> *define*. Python only has declarations for scope (`global` and `nonlocal`), which aren't being used here.